# Filter nested array based on _id

Tags: javascript

How to get item where id is: '60da3d5ce6cdd45d6dbc56bd'?

[image]

Comment: Could you describe your case better: what the structure of your data is, provide an example in code? Did you try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?

Answer (score 0):

Use

- flat function => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat
- filter function => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

It will return the first value satisfying condition

Something like:

```
const data = [
  [{_id: 1}, {_id: 2}, {_id: 2}, {_id: '60da3d5ce6cdd45d6dbc56bd'}],
  [{_id: 1}, {_id: 2}, {_id: 2}],
  [{_id: 1}, {_id: 2}, {_id: 2}]
]

data.flat().find(e => e._id === '60da3d5ce6cdd45d6dbc56bd')
// output { _id: '60da3d5ce6cdd45d6dbc56bd' }
```

works just fine

Comment: thank you for the answer but im gettting all the items as one array instead of  just the item that matches the id

Comment: Edited answer, flat is perfect for that

Comment: yes it works now in the console but when i try to use it example: `data.name` im getting this errorr 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')'.  thank you

Comment: edit your question and show not working code